# Umbraco Level 2 Certification

Tags: umbraco

I am an .NET developer and would like to learn Umbraco.

I see best way to learn Umbraco is to attend their Master Class (Level 1 and Level 2)

I am interested in umbraco Level 2 certification. Do I need to attend Umbraco Level 1 before that?

Best Regards
Hardeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do a level 1 to do a level 2.  I did never do a level 1, only a level 2.  But I had experience with a few umbraco websites.  Further more, if you want to become a certified company, you need 4 exams.  If you only do a level 2, that will count only for one exam.

I would suggest you do both, even though you don't need it.